# Otp should not accessed after 4 hours

Tags: java, date, oracle11g

I have written a code for verification through email by sending otp. I have to configure in such a way that if the user enters the otp after 4 hours it should not be accepted.
I have used date object with if conditions and it works fine but is there any way to achieve same in less coding.

```
Date dateFromDatabase=emailData.getBody().getUpdated();

if((dateFromDatabase.getYear()-date.getYear())==0){

    if((dateFromDatabase.getMonth()-date.getMonth())==0){

        if((dateFromDatabase.getDay()-date.getDay())==0){
            if((dateFromDatabase.getHours()-date.getHours())<=4){
                System.out.print("May Be Right otp");

                if( emailData.getBody().getHASHCODE().equals(fromotp)){
                    System.out.print("matched");
                    emails.setId(emailData.getBody().getId());
                    emails .setVERIFIED(1);
                    emails.setHASHCODE("");
                    emails.setEmails(To);
                    //updateEmails(emails);
                    String Subject="Pharmerz Thanknote";
                    String Acknowledge="Thank you for verifying on Pharmerz";
                    email.SendMail(To,Subject,Acknowledge);
                    Emails saveEmails =emailService.create( emails );
                    return new ResponseEntity<Emails>(emails,HttpStatus.OK);

                }else{
                    System.out.print("miss matched");
                    emailService.delete(emailData.getBody().getId());
                    return new ResponseEntity<Emails>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                }



            }else{
                System.out.print("Wrong or Old Otp");
                emailService.delete(emailData.getBody().getId());
                return new ResponseEntity<Emails>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }else{
            System.out.print("Wrong or Old Otp");
            emailService.delete(emailData.getBody().getId());
            return new ResponseEntity<Emails>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

    }else{
        System.out.print("Wrong or Old Otp");
        emailService.delete(emailData.getBody().getId());
        return new ResponseEntity<Emails>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
else{
    System.out.print("Wrong or Old Otp");
    emailService.delete(emailData.getBody().getId());
    return new ResponseEntity<Emails>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: What is `Date`? `java.sql.Date`, `java.util.Date`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
Date dateFromDatabase = // get the date from the database

long duration  = dateFromDatabase.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration);
```

You can use the `diffInHours` variable and perform your business logic.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.between(                      // Span-of-time unattached to timeline.
    myUtilDate.toInstant() ,           // Convert legacy java.util.Date object to modern java.time.Instant.
    Instant.now()                      // Get the current moment.
).compareTo( Duration.ofHours( 4 ) )   // Ask if the time span variance exceeds our limit of four hours.
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes.

I assume your `Date` object at top of code is a `java.util.Date`. That class is part of the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## Using java.time

### `Instant`

Convert that `Date` to its modern equivalent: `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant then = myUtilDate.toInstant();
```

Apparently you want to compare this against the current moment and look for a four-hour variance, though your Question is not clear.

Get the current moment is simple.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

### `Duration`

Represent a span of time unattached to the timeline as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

```
Duration variance = Duration.between( then , now );
```

Check for a negative duration, meaning the past moment is actually showing as future.

```
if( variance.isNegative() ) { … handle error condition … }
```

Compare that duration to our limit of 4 hours. If the time span between then and now is over four hours, `compareTo` returns a positive number (number greater than zero).

```
Duration limit = Duration.ofHours( 4 );
Boolean exceededLimit = ( variance.compareTo( limit ) > 0 ) ; // If the time span between then and now is over four hours, `compareTo` returns a positive number (number greater than zero).
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).